# Python JSON formatting data management

Tags: python, json, weather-api

I am trying to extract needed data from **JSON** data from **Open weather maps** API in **Python (2.7)**!
JSON file looks something like this.

```
{u'calctime': 0.0331,
 u'cnt': 2,
 u'cod': u'200',
 u'list': [{u'clouds': {u'all': 75},
            u'coord': {u'lat': 45.551109, u'lon': 18.69389},
            u'distance': 0.001,
            u'dt': 1351870200,
            u'id': 3193935,
            u'main': {u'humidity': 93,
                      u'pressure': 1008,
                      u'temp': 287.15,
                      u'temp_max': 291.18,
                      u'temp_min': 287.15},
            u'name': u'Osijek',
            u'weather': [{u'description': u'broken clouds',
                          u'icon': u'04d',
                          u'id': 803,
                          u'main': u'Clouds'}],
            u'wind': {u'deg': 70, u'speed': 4.6}},
           {u'clouds': {u'all': 75},
            u'coord': {u'lat': 45.568611, u'lon': 18.61389},
            u'distance': 6.526,
            u'dt': 1351870200,
            u'id': 3187657,
            u'main': {u'humidity': 93,
                      u'pressure': 1008,
                      u'temp': 285.43,
                      u'temp_max': 287.15,
                      u'temp_min': 282.15},
            u'name': u'Visnjevac',
            u'weather': [{u'description': u'light intensity shower rain',
                          u'icon': u'09d',
                          u'id': 520,
                          u'main': u'Rain'}],
            u'wind': {u'deg': 70, u'speed': 4.6}}],
 u'message': u'Model=GFS-OWM, '}
```

This is weather data for two geographical points. I know how to extract single data from the both points (for example humidity or temperature) by using json package but problem is that I can not extract multiple data of the same type put from different geographical points. In this example I want to extract/print names of those points (osijek, visnjevac).

Is there a way to that  with json encoder/decder?

Comment: Why can you not extract multiple data points? What have you tried, how did it fail? I very much doubt this is a JSON decoder problem.

Comment: Also, when you say "looks like this", are you saying that the code you posted *is* the JSON file, or is the Python data structure you get after *decoding* the JSON? (Because it's not JSON--`u''` is Python syntax for a unicode string, not JSON.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is not JSON, it is a Python object, so I am assuming you already passed the original JSON string through `json.loads()` or something similar.

To extract the `'name'` values for each dictionary in the list of cities, you can use the following:

```
names = [city['name'] for city in data['list']]
```

Result:

```
>>> names
[u'Osijek', u'Visnjevac']
```

The assumes you have the content from your post in the variable `data`.

Comment: Thank you for fast reply and solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add to F.J's answer that, if you wanted to dynamicaly extract data for specific cities, you could do something like this:

```
cities = ['osijek', 'visnjevac']
cities_data = filter(lambda i: i['name'].lower() in cities, data['list'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find useful my GitHub Python project [PyOWM](https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm), which is a simple object-oriented client wrapper around the Open Weather Map web API.